# How to use similar lexers

Tags: antlr

I have the following grammar:

```
cmds
    : cmd+
    ;

cmd
    : include_cmd  |  other_cmd
    ;

include_cmd
    : INCLUDE  DOUBLE_QUOTE  FILE_NAME  DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

other_cmd
    : CMD_NAME  ARG+
    ;


INCLUDE
    : '#include'
    ;

DOUBLE_QUOTE
    : '"'
    ;

CMD_NAME
    : ('a'..'z')*
    ;

ARG
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')+
    ;

FILE_NAME
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '.')+
    ;
```

So the difference between CMD_NAME, ARG and FILE_NAME is not large, CMD_NAME must be lower case letters, ARG can have upper case letter and "_" and FILE_NAME yet can have ".".

But this has a problem, when I test the rule with - #include "abc", 'abc' is interpreted as CMD_NAME instead of FILE_NAME, I think it is because CMD_NAME is before FILE_NAME in the grammar file, this leads to parsing error.

Do I have to rely on such technique as predict to deal with this? Is there a pure EBNF solution other than relying on host programming language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this has a problem, when I test the rule with - #include "abc", 'abc' is interpreted as CMD_NAME instead of FILE_NAME, I think it is because CMD_NAME is before FILE_NAME in the grammar file, this leads to parsing error.

The set of all valid `CMD_NAME`s intersects with the set of all valid `FILE_NAME`s. Input `abc` qualifies as both. The lexer matches the input with the first rule listed (as you suspected) because it's the first one matched.

> Do I have to rely on such technique as [predicate] to deal with this? Is there a pure EBNF solution other than relying on host programming language?

It depends on what you're willing accept in your grammar. Consider changing your `include_cmd` rule to something more conventional, like this:

```
include_cmd : INCLUDE STRING;

STRING 
    : '"' ~('"'|'\r'|'\n')* '"' {String text = getText(); setText(text.substring(1, text.length() - 1));}
    ;
```

Now input `#include "abc"` turns into tokens `[INCLUDE : #include] [STRING : abc]`.

I don't think the grammar should be responsible for determining whether a file name is valid or not: a valid file *name* doesn't imply a valid *file*, and the grammar has to understand OS file naming conventions (valid characters, paths, etc) that probably have no bearing on the grammar itself. I think you'll be fine if you're willing to drop rule `FILE_NAME` for something like the rules the above.

Also worth noting, your `CMD_NAME` rule matches zero-length input. Consider changing `('a'..'z')*` to `('a'..'z')+` unless a `CMD_NAME` really can be empty.

---

Keep in mind, too, that you'll have the same problem with `ARG` that you did with `FILE_NAME`. It's listed after `CMD_NAME`, so any input that qualifies for both rules (like `abc` again) will hit `CMD_NAME`. Consider breaking these rules up into more conventional ones like so:

```
other_cmd : ID (ID | NUMBER)+ SEMI;   //instead of CMD_NAME ARG+
ID        : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')+; //instead of CMD_NAME, "id" part of ARG
NUMBER    : ('0'..'9')+;              //"number" part of ARG
SEMI      : ';';
```

I added rule `SEMI` to mark the end of a command. Otherwise the parser won't know if input `a b c d` is supposed to be one command with three arguments (`a(b,c,d)`) or two commands with one argument each (`a(b), c(d)`).

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation, it is clear now. I do have one question though, will ask in a new thread.